# Wiring two separate circuits with separate loads (one with mosfet and Arduino) with a single bench PSU

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet, 12v, nmos

I have a cheapo bench PSU with one pair of terminals on it and I am trying to wire the pictured circuit correctly and in best possible practice. As my description on the *schematic* says, one LED device will be under the control of Arduino/mosfet/buttons combo, while the other LED device will be wired in a plain manner, straight to the power source, with a basic toggle switch to turn it on/off.

I tried to wire it as best as I know, since this is workbench environment I don't have anything but crocodile clips, but there was a mistake on my part because the "Arduino controlled" LED didn't shut off completely when Arduino said it should, it would turn off to 50% brightness, and the MOSFET got superhot. Also, I do have to say it, in my Arduino code every pin is used with "INPUT_PULLUP" rule applied.

So, before I smoke something here I'm asking for some help, maybe some of you can scribble the proper wiring approach on this diagram. My understanding on how to properly ground things in this scenario is not the best. Thanks for help!

[image]

Comment: MOSFET  S to ground,  D to LED minus, G to MCU output. LED plus to PS +. If it does not work, you burned transistor. One button to MCU input and ground.

Comment: I tried to simulate how I'd wire this thing using these crocodile clips I have, so I hope you don't mind my crocodile symbol standard in this schematic :D but is this the correct way then? Also I'm reading something about high side low side mosfet switch...is this something I should consider here too?

https://i.imgur.com/Lv0mLYZ.jpg

Comment: N-channel MOSFET used as low side switch , connect load to ground. P-channel is usd as high side switch, connecting to PS+. But control signal more complicated, should be used another transistor to pull gate to +12V.

Comment: Why do you need the buck converter? Are you using an Arduino flavor that doesn't have an on board regulator?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser if this circuit proves to work nicely in my bench test, it will be used in a 12V DC environment, so some spikes in voltage are possible, I just want to keep Arduino safe in 5V with the buck.

Comment: Arduino Uno and similar boards work fine when powered through the Vin with 12V as long as you don't add additional 5V loads. A few pull-ups at 5 kOhm are no problem.

Comment: What is the LED light part number or LED current rating?

Answer (score 1):

This wiring scheme should suffice, but your really don't need the additional 5V regulator.

[image]

[Link to TinkerCAD Circuit](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9omEFZWkK9v-frantic-wluff/editel?sharecode=DGqGYiVs6kebkreNAaACav9cJg8IaBKAE-4mZt5WvS8)

Comment: Thanks for the sketch! I'm confused on the mosfet resistors, is gate bridged with source, why is that?

Comment: I do that out of habit of working with some open collector outputs. It's not strictly necessary for push-pull outputs like on the Arduino, but I like to include it just as a reminder that the gate needs a discharge path to turn off quickly. If your particular application really needs to full V+ of the output on the gate, it can most likely be omitted without consequence.

Comment: I would like to run my vehicle headlights (12V DC) with Arduino control and mosfet for sequence, so not well educated to asses if such approach with bridged source-gate is needed.

Comment: @Varonne If you are connecting to car please add that to question since that changes many requirements and if the 12V is from a car battery

Comment: @Ernesto my mistake! I figured 12V from bench will emulate my motorcycle battery. The LED bulb is H7 12V chinese thing with no other rating on the box - but from what I  managed to google it has 30W, so 2.5A typical vehicle led bulb.

So wiring the Arduino and Mosfet in the motorcycle battery circuit changes the layout?